# Eclipse not picking up Windows PATH

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I have several projects in my workspace.  When I run projectA with:

```
System.out.println("PATH=" + System.getenv("PATH"));
```

It prints the windows path (the same when you are in cmd and say set path)

When I run projectB, I get null for my PATH printout...I have no clue why this is, I've never had Eclipse act in this way.  There is a DLL my code relies on being able to find so I can't run it without it knowing about the path.  Any suggestions?

Comment: In eclipse, under build path options for the project, then under Environment... you can override Environmental variables. Does the project in question override the PATH variable explicitly?

Comment: Is it just PATH? i.e. Are any of the other environment variables populated or are they all blank? (`System.getenv()` will return a `Map<String,String>` of all environment info).

Comment: What happens when you create a new project? Is `PATH` still omitted from the environment variable list?

Comment: Small update to this...I tried the same problem project with a different debug configuration and it worked!  But it will not work for this one specific debug configuration.  I have some different environment variables set (not path) and a different user library for the classpath but that's it.